# What happened to the triggerOnce option in Waypoints 3.0?

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I recently upgraded jquery-waypoints from 2.x to 3.x in my project and found that a lot of my code broke. All references to `$(this)` within my handlers had to be changed to `$(this.element)` which, once I figured out was the cause of my troubles, was easy enough to fix.

I haven't been able to figure out what happened to the `triggerOnce` option which would prevent a waypoint from firing multiple times. Any idea why this was removed and how can I achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  Adding this.disable() to the end of my handler disables the waypoint after it's been fired, preventing it from being called again.  I really think this should be documented.

Comment: I use `this.destroy` at the end of handler instead because ( in my case ) I know I'll never use that instance again anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I know an answer was already marked as correct, but I'd like to expand beyond a simple comment.

3.0, being a major version, made breaking changes. One of them was the removal of `triggerOnce`. It is noted in the [changelog](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/blob/79903c88ed2564b6df6fb850e8430f1f68fa7f1e/CHANGELOG.md). It is also mentioned in the [destroy docs](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/destroy/) where using `destroy` at the end of the handler is called out as an alternative to the old `triggerOnce`.

Previously, `triggerOnce` wasn't the exact same as calling `destroy` because all Waypoint methods were called on jQuery objects. The elements in those jQuery objects may have multiple waypoints attached to them, but there was no way to separate them once they were created. If you called `destroy` all waypoints on that element were destroyed. The `triggerOnce` option, however, worked on an individual waypoint basis behind the scenes. Now that 3.0 returns instances of the Waypoint class directly and `this` within the handler is a reference to the Waypoint instance instead of the element, there is no difference between `triggerOnce` and calling `this.destroy()` to end a handler. So the code was removed.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details and thanks for creating a fantastic jQuery plugin.  I just wanted to note, however, that I tried searching for quite a while for a mention of triggerOnce before posting here.  It's a hard thing to search for since Waypoints has been around for awhile and there are a lot of mentions of triggerOnce on pages that are still indexed by Google but that now redirect to the new homepage.  I think a dedicated page in the documentation on tips to migrate from 2x to 3x would be hugely beneficial. Thanks again!

Comment: Yaron, I agree a migration guide may be needed. It was originally on the slate as an another Guide page but I decided to hold off until I saw what actual issues people were having in migration. Like this issue here. :)

Comment: @imakewebthings what if i am calling waypoints like so `$this.waypoint(counterUpper, { offset: '100%', triggerOnce: true });` ? where would the destroy function fit in ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Inside `counterUpper`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable a jQuery waypoint (v3.0):

```
$('.my-waypoint').waypoint(function(direction){
  // Do some stuff
  this.destroy();
});
```