# why is my waypoints destroy function call throwing a error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I decided to play around with waypoints.js(jQuery version) a bit, [Heres](http://purplefront.net/waypoints_scroll_effect/animation.html) what i have so far:

The destroy waypoints has the following code attached to it as of now:

```
$('.destroy').on('click' , function(){
             console.log(ways);
            ways.destroy();
        });
```

You'll see this code in the animation.js file .

When i click on the button , i get the following message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ways.destroy is not a function
```

Why ? , i checked the waypoints.js file and it does indeed have a destroy function , also the waypoints , have a very [similar example](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/destroy/) for the destroy function , similar to the way i have used the destroy function.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you actually see from that `log` statement?

Comment: @MattBurland , i get quite a big object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Initializing waypoints , like so , did solve the problem:

```
ways =  new Waypoint({

            element : osTrigger,
            handler : function(){
              osElement.addClass('animated').addClass(osAnimationClass);
              this.destroy();
            },
            offset : '50%'

        });
```

I was doing it wrong by doing the following:

```
   ways =  osTrigger.waypoint(function() {
          osElement.addClass('animated').addClass(osAnimationClass);
         },{
           offset: '50%'
     });
```

So yes, having a closer look at the documentation and realizing that the new version of waypoints.js has a different set of methods did solve my problem.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629472/what-happened-to-the-triggeronce-option-in-waypoints-3-0) for further reference.

Answer (score 2):

`ways` (of length 1) containing a the object. Try `ways[0].destroy()`.

This is a common issue when selecting DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

`ways` is an Array containing one Waypoint object, so you need to do this:

```
ways[0].destroy();
```

Comment: well ways[0] need not necessarily be a HTML element right ?

Comment: not necessarily, but if you debug your code, and open that array in your log, you'll see that it contains a waypoint object.

Answer (score 1):

because `ways` is an array of `waypoints`,
you'd have to call `ways[0].destroy()`